# Radix Sort: what does "groups" means in radix sort?

Tags: sorting, radix

I have sorting algorithm assignment for my cs class. I need to convert pseudocode of Radix Sort into c++. Here's my pseudocode:

```
radixSort( int theArray[], in n:integer, in d:integer)
// sort n d-digit integers in the array theArray
    for (j=d down to 1) {
         Initialize 10 groups to empty
         Initialize a counter for each group to 0
         for (i=0 through n-1) {
              k = jth digit of theArray[i]
              Place theArray[i] at the end of group k
              Increase kth counter by 1
         }
         Replace the items in theArray with all the items in 
         group 0, followed by all the items in group 1, and so on.
    }
```

The problem is that, I really don't understand what "groups" means. I try to do with array first but, of course, it overrides the numbers. How can I groups numbers according to their last digit? I am not asking for any code. I just need to understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: nice explanation on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Comment: It says that "LSD radix sort can be achieved using queues as buckets." but in C code example, the writer just use a bucket as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Take each number, divide by 10 raised to the power of x, with x being each iteration of the loop, then mod that number by 10.

```
(num/10**x) % 10
```

This will give you the least significant digit on the first pass, then move to each digit in order of right to left. The number of iterations should be equal to the length of the largest number.